# How to have a template link leave the django app

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

I'm attempting to have a hyperlink leave the Django application I am building.
What I found through another Stackoverflow page was:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a> doesn't work, but
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a> does break the link from the site.
```

My issue with the above is the certain link I am attempting to get to doesn't work when linked with https:// in front of it. Is there a different way to set a hyperlink to link outside of my application without requiring the https://?

Comment: No there isn't. And note this has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Any chance you could explain a bit more?

Comment: i think you should elaborate more on "does break the link from the site". both links should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with django. It is pure HTML. There are 3 ways to get to some other page:

`<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>` - this will target ssl http protocol

`<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>` - this will target standard http protocol

`<a href="//google.com">Google</a>` - this will use same protocol as your site is using (if your server is `https` it will target `https://google.com`, if your server is `http` it will target `http://google.com`)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out http:// is what I needed, not https://. Why is it one worked with the url I needed to use and the other broke it?

Comment: Because the site you're linking to doesn't support https.